# Discrepancy between JMeter's Response Time in Summary Report and Response Times Over Time Graph

Tags: jmeter

I hope that someone will help me to determine the reason of the discrepancy between the response time data in Summary Report and Response Times over Time.

Here's the data of the Summary Report:

[image]

**.jtl (Summary Report) graph**
[image]

As you can see the Summary Report's average response time when clicking login is 2354 ms.

Here's the graph of Response Times over Time.
[image]

[image]
Here, the average response time when clicking login is 2723 ms.

**Comparing the two graphs, the second graph (in pink) is missing a "16000ms" response time.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any "discrepancy" there, according to the [documentation](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ResponseTimesOverTime/):

> This graph will display for each sampler the average response time in milliseconds

Average response time is basically an [arithmetic mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_mean) of indiviaual sampler's response times and the chart shows the response times over the test timeline with the given [granularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Granularity)

So looking into:

1. Spike above 12 seconds
2. Right part of the chart which is mostly below 2 seconds.

I would say that the chart is accurate. You can open your .jtl result file using [LibreOffice Calc](https://www.libreoffice.org/discover/calc/) or equivalent and generate the same chart using [`Elapsed`](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207420385-Glossary) column - it should be the same.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Going back, I updated my previous post, I added the graph of the .jtl file (summary report). Please see the blue graph. Can you help me why the second graph (in pink) is missing a 16000 ms response time?

Comment: @KennethP. Did you get an answer for this? I am having the same problem.

Comment: Dang, I just found out the graph is grouped per second.

Comment: Do I need to explain "granularity" word more verbose?